# vCenter login: An error occurred when processing the metadata during vCenter Single Sign-On setup

Tags: passwords, user-accounts, esxi, vsphere, vcenter

Recently, I took over management of some servers, and I can no longer connect to our vCenter to manage our VMs. We don't have SSO and as far as I know, we only have one account "admin".

When I go on the web using server name, I get error as below:

> A server error occurred.
>   [400] An error occurred while sending an authentication request to the vCenter Single Sign-On server - An error occurred when processing the metadata during vCenter Single Sign-On setup - null.

Check the vSphere Web Client server logs for details"

When use IP of the sever, I get following error:

> [400] An error occurred while sending a logout request to the vCenter Single Sign-On server - An error occurred when processing the metadata during vCenter Single Sign-On setup - null. Back to login screen

I see a 90 policy enforced, however nothing I do seems to resolve the issue.

Solutions i have tried so far and did not help:
restarting the server, reset password, I have check the logs and nothing to be found of recent. last logs were from 2019. the problem started monday 8/0602020 etc.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Comment: "Check the vSphere Web Client server logs for details" Have you done this? Please [edit] and include the log in the question.

Comment: I have check the logs and nothing to be found of recent. last logs were from 2019.
the problem started monday 8/0602020

Comment: if last logs are from 2019 then either your disk is full or the services are not running. check with `df -h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your problem is caused by the STS certificate and other certificate expired, look at this VMware KB:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/76719